# How am I able to assign an IP to a bridge interface

Tags: networking, bridge

From what I read, bridging happens below IP layer, yet how am I able to assign an IP to a bridge interface ?

```
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig br0 IP promisc up
```

What does the OS do ? it sounds like it provides me a ip network stack on top of br0.

Can iptable rules work on top of this interface then ?

THx.
PS : not interested in ebtables. Iam more interested in the concept of what happens under the hood when i assign IP to a bridge interface.

Comment: In some ways you can think of the 'br0' as a virtual interface that is a member of the bridge in addition to the physical interfaces configured for that bridge.  For anything layer 3 and above, just treat it like another interface that just happens to have some magic going on at the lower layers that you don't care about.

Comment: Or you can think of a bridge like a switch, and the machine with the bridge has an interface connected to that switch too.

Answer (score 1):

Bridging essentially shows up on the computer as another interface that you would normally configure like any other networking interface.

In general, the process is as follows:

1. brctl addbr br0
2. brctl addif br0 eth0
3. brctl addif br0 eth1

Now, you use the other commands as usual to add interfaces. Each distro's autoconfig works a little differently, for example, in RHEL6.x

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
...
IPADDR="0.0.0.0"
BRIDGE="br0"
...

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
...
DEVICE="br0"
TYPE="Bridge"
IPADDR="10.0.0.1"
```

Here's a [good article with more details](http://www.banym.de/linux/centos/setup-bridge-device-on-centos), for CentOS

Here's the [official kernel documentation](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/BRIDGE-STP-HOWTO/set-up-the-bridge.html) for brctl.

**iptables**
Now, with the basics out of the way -- bridging is really heavy-duty in linux. Bridging occurs at a lower level in the network stack and thus things are already being done to these frames before they even transverse iptables. This is a wiiiiide topic, so here's a good page with lots of diagrams.

http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use iptables atop a bridge, however ebtables is the more correct way of doing it.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that ebtables is more correct without any qualifications.  For layer 3 filtering and above you really should be using iptables, just because what your filtering happens to enter/exit via a bridged interface shouldn't matter.